# Can Automapper Project().To<T> be customized on a per call basis?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata, automapper, iqueryable

I have a simple EF query, that needs to be passed back up to the client as IQueryable for an OData Web API controller.

The query I make looks like this:

```
var query = _context.Diary
                    .Where(bd => bd.EventStart < DateTime.Now)
                    .Project()
                    .To<FeedbackViewModel>();
```

However, I am trying to translate some old code that did not use the OData providers and would follow the database call with this (simplified greatly):

```
var mappedData = Mapper.Map<List<FeedbackViewModel>>(query);
foreach (var feedbackViewModel in mappedData)
{
    if (feedbackViewModel.UserId == userId)
    {
        feedbackViewModel.ViewingWith = GetOtherUserDetails();
    }
    else
    {
        feedbackViewModel.ViewingWith = GetThisUsersDetails();
    }        
}
```

How can I encapsulate the logic of the `if` statement into the automapper projection?

Comment: Perhaps [Conditional Mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conditional-mapping) can help you?

Comment: That looks like something different, i.e. should a given property be mapped. I need something that lets me map based on a given rule, with external variables.

Comment: The only way you can accomplish what you're trying to do is if the variables are within the class you are trying to map from. In which case, you could do something like... "Mapper.CreateMap<BaseType, List<FeedbackViewModel>>().ForMember(s => s.BaseVar, t => T.MapFrom(u => BaseClassToListFeedBackViewModelFunc(b)); (pseudo-code)

Comment: Could you provide your current mapping logic and the members of the Diary class?